DAX RLS Function using LOOKUPVALUE Parsing but not working
I have a table that I'm trying to implement RLS on using a secondary table with a structure below:
EmployeeTable



EmployeeID
EmployeeEmail




1
1234@email.com


2
4567@email.com



FilterTable



EmployeeID
ManagerHierarchy




1
3&4&5


2
6&7&4&5



The ManagerHierarchy column is a string that shows all managers of an employee concatenated together and separated by "&".
The goal of the RLS is to create a filter that allows any manager to view the report and have their data only display employeeIDs wherein their own ID exists within the ManagerHierarchy column and thus only showing their subordinates.
I have the below DAX expression applied on EmployeeTable that I thought would work and parses in the expression builder, but it is giving me errors:
[EmplID]=
LOOKUPVALUE(
FilterTable[EmployeeID], FilterTable[ManagerHIERARCHY],

LOOKUPVALUE( //This is to return the viewer's own employeeID to be crossed over into the FilterTable
[EmployeeID], [EmployeeEmail], USERPRINCIPALNAME())
)

The Report it gives is as follows:
An error was encoutnered during the evaluation of the row level security defined on EmployeeTable. Function 'LOOKUPVALUE' does not support values of type Text with values of type integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.
I've tried re-shuffling my DAX expression with to convert it as such, but I haven't been able to make it work as intended.

You're searching FilterTable[ManagerHIERARCHY] (a text column) with a EmployeeTable[EmployeeID] which is an integer... may be switch the first two params of your first function.

I would avoid the need for complex DAX (hard to code and test - especially in the context of security) by splitting the ManagerHierarchy column into multiple rows.
The Power Query Editor can easily handle this - select the column and from the Home ribbon choose Split Column / By Delimiter. Specify the "&" character as the delimiter (if the editor doesn't guess that), Split at = each occurrence, and then in the Advanced options section choose Split into = Rows.
If you need to preserve your current data structure, this could be a new query, starting by Reference to your existing FilterTable query.
After that transformation, the DAX expression you wrote can be used to apply Row Level Security.
Personally I would go a step further in the Query design, and add steps to Merge Queries / Expand to copy the Manager's Email ID onto each row of the FilterTable. This would make the security implementation even easier to code and test. It would also be much more transparent e.g. for a security audit.
From experience, testing and building confidence in any Power BI security implementation is difficult (can't impersonate without granting access) and high-risk. Mistakes can be really embarrassing and burn confidence in your solution. The best approach is always to keep the technical details of the security design as simple as possible, so you can involve many others in signing off the testing.  A solution that involves complex code only understood by and visible to a handful of developers would typically not pass a security audit.
